# How to use multi select in App Builder to assign the value in attribute using design:component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, multi-select

[image]

I want to Input multiple vales in an attribute but i can't find the perfect solution. i want like following Image . I Have tried with Dynamic Select List but it is not Multipick list and when I use  it give me  "Only Boolean, Integer or String attributes may be exposed in design files.: Source " Error

Comment: Please elaborate you requirement and also post how far you've reached.

Comment: I have use dynamic  picklist  .
<design:component >
    <design:attribute name="mycustomlist" datasource="apex://MyCustomPickList" />
</design:component>

Comment: Have you tried using `type="String[]"`? If not, can you not use a multi-select picklist here?

Comment: yes but it give me error "Only Boolean, Integer or String attributes may be exposed in design files.: Source"

Comment: these are all things you should have included in your post initially. please update accordingly, alongside any specific requirements and context.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible so far. You can only have attributes of type Integer, String, or Boolean as described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm).

You can have dynamic picklist values, but not multi-picklist. Have a look [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_dynamic_picklists.htm).

You can still create an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) for it and post the link on this thread.

Comment: I created an idea : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000015BI1QAM